# Question about voltage and current relationship

Tags: voltage, current

How can 12v push hundreds of amps, let's say 500amps at 0.024 ohms? clearly the starter motor can't have that little of resistance to turn the engine rapidly. Is there a some sort of boost converter included?

Comment: Sort of, the pinion on the starter motor is very small compared to the ring gear attached to the crank shaft giving you a mechanical boost =-D

Comment: Clearly it can't? Clearly it must.

Comment: where are you getting these numbers from?

Comment: manufacturer sticker on battery, 12v. Numbers vary depending on battery type. The ohms are calculated if 500amps were needed to start the engine, cold start in this case.

Comment: Have you ever tried turning an engine over by hand? It requires a great deal of energy, hence a powerful motor that draw lots of current. Resistance is only part of the equation as a lot more of the energy you put into it produces movement than produces heat.

Answer (score 4):

> clearly the starter motor can't have that little of resistance to turn the engine rapidly

The starter motor does have a low enough resistance to draw the current it needs to turn the engine straight from the 12v battery. And it doesn't need to turn the engine 'rapidly', just fast enough.

Comment: But when i measure the resistance from battery + to starter motor it shows about 0.5ohms. If, using ohm's law, 12v, 500amps 0.024ohm doesn't make sense

Comment: @bujashaka if your wires are 0.5R you are not pulling 500A. Where r u getting these numbers from/

Comment: @bujashaka, for low resistances, you can't just use a normal meter to measure. You have to use specialized meters (with 4 wires) or other techniques.

Comment: @bujashaka do you have your dmm on a scaled reading?

Comment: @bujashaka and is that resistance with the contactor engaged?

Comment: Most of the current creates the torque and that's where most of the power goes, a smaller proportion of the current warms the resistance of the windings. The motor is not a resistor; it presents as a resistance, which is not the same thing.

Comment: @Chu All of the current creates torque, some of which is lost in friction. The back EMF, due to the rotation speed, plus the current*resistance of the windings, is equal to the applied voltage.

Comment: @Neil_UK Some of the current warms the motor - heat in \$I^2R\$ losses and friction. Most of the current provides useful torque. I don't think my comment is incorrect or misleading.

Comment: @Chu: I think Neil is right: All of the *current* produces torque since it all runs through the windings in the magnetic field. As it does the power is split between useful torque and losses due to resistance as you correctly stated in your comment three up from here.

Comment: my 500amps was just theory example. Trying to understand how ohm's law is applied to the car starting motor because i can't understand how 12v is able to push example 500amps when resistance must be so low according to the ohm's law. But what i do know is that 12v battery according to manufacturer, should be able to push 500amps.

Comment: If you need to draw 500 amps from a 10v battery (the voltage sags under load, and it keeps the sums simple) then the total resistance of the starter motor AND the cables and contactor must be less than 10/500 = 20m ohms. This is why the cables are so thick. 1m of 100mm2 cable has a resistance of 170u ohms, so you can start to see that it's possible. Generally, if it happens, it must be true.

Comment: Just to make it absolutely clear. If you attach a normal meter to a wire to measure its resistance, the number you get will not be meaningful. So your 0.5 Ohm measurement confirms that the resistance is pretty low, but you cannot say anything more than that. Is it 1mOhm? 100 uOhm? 10 mOhm? You simply cannot tell with a normal meter.

Comment: To further clarify mkeith's comment, with a normal meter (well, mine anyway, and I'll bet yours too) on the minimum resistance scale with test prods, the reading accuracy is about +/- 1 ohm. Much of this is the variable contact resistance of the prod to device under test. So if the wire resistance is << 1 ohm, the meter is well within its specification if it says anything in the 0 or 1 region. Car starter cables and other low resistance items are measured using a '4-terminal' method. You shove a test current though it, and measure the voltage across it *with a different set of probes*.

Comment: so the cable doesn't actually have that 0,5ohms but much more less? then this start to make sense!

Comment: I used some online wire calculator resistance for copper wiring. It's no where near 0.5ohms, actually it's fractions. So my multimeter half of ohm confused me.

Comment: @bujashaka I keep these figures in my head. A 1m length of 1mm2 copper wire has a resistance of about 17m ohms. This is much easier to scale to practical lengths/areas mentally than the 1.68e-8 ohms for a 1 metre cube, which is what you'll get in data tables. Copper increases resistance with temperature by about 10% for every 25 degrees Celcius, most pure metals also do by a similar amount.

Answer (score 2):

Some vehicles will draw 1000A and more - the large HGV's (Heavy Goods Vehicle or also known as TIR - Trans International Routiers) for example, so cars in the range of 2 to 3 litres are usually around 400 to 600 Amps - just look at the thickness of the cables linking battery to starter...

However, newer starters have better technology and the current is coming down, but, if you think of the power needed to get an engine turning sufficiently fast to start then the current draw is significant.

If you take a starter motor apart - most of its weight is due to the amount of copper used in its construction.

And, a battery terminal can disappear in a puff of smoke if it is left loose and someone tries to start a 6 litre inline diesel .... I had to get the terminal on the battery replaced... Oh and it was not me - I was helping a mate out - replace terminal or new battery...

Comment: Heavy Goods Vehicle ...